# gdm3 hangs on logout (black screen)

Tags: gdm3

I currently have installed 'kali-desktop-gnome' on a kali live with encrypted persistence which automatically installs gdm3. I have gdm3 configured as the default display manager. Everything is fine except that I get a black screen as soon as I log out. The only way I can fix this situation is to reboot.
Both kali linux and gdm3 are up to date.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little more, I came across this: [GDM3 does not start in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-does-not-start-in-ubuntu-18-04). In my case, this configuration fixed the issue:

> The solution in my particular case was to deactivate Wayland modifying `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` uncommenting or enabling `WaylandEnable=false` so the GNOME display manager will always load the GNOME desktop environment from `gnome-desktop` and not Wayland. This is because Wayland usually has errors with some graphics drivers.